# .htaccess and robots.txt rewrite url how to

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, robots.txt

Here is my code for .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index.html
```

**Problem : when visit mydomain.com/robots.txt then page again redirect to index.html**
**Required :**

```
if(url contain robots.txt) Then   
    redirect to mydomain.com/robots.txt   
else   
    redirect to index.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.html
```

Basically, those two `RewriteCond` tell apache to rewrite the URL **only if** the requested file (`-f`) or directory (`-d`) doesn't exists (the `!` serves as a negation).

Alternatively, if you need it just for `robots.txt` you can use something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$
```

instead of the two `RewriteCond` above.

Comment: can you please give me your contact, facebook, skype or any email.

Comment: what's mean of %{REQUEST_URI} and RewriteCond

Comment: @Wasim basically, RewriteCond is like saying "if CONDITION then". REQUEST_URI is the actual passed URI: http://domain.tld/robots.txt. Take a look: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html