# Redirecting robots.txt to a php page

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, robots.txt

I have a system that handles multiple domains under one file structure and each domain would need different sitemap and robots.txt.

For sitemap I have set up a redirect and I know it works well. I would like to confirm that same is possible with robots.txt?

I have added a rewrite rule in .htaccess that redirects person to a php page. On this php page I find what domain user has and print out correct information with text header.

Is this allowed?

Extra info:

I have a codeigniter application that is used by domainA and domainB. while domainA should see robots for domainA, domainB should see robots for domainB. And if i am to create robots.txt in the root of the site both domainA and domainB would have access to it, due to that I have created a separate php page to give out correct robots for domainA and B.

In .htaccess i have a rewrite rule similar to:

```
RewriteRule   ^robots.txt$ func/getRobots/$1 [L]
```

---

After looking around I was able to identify that other people do it:
http://www.aberdeencloud.com/docs/guides/how-use-different-robotstxt-development-and-live-environments

[.htaccess and robots.txt rewrite url how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930866/htaccess-and-robots-txt-rewrite-url-how-to)

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61654/redirect-google-crawler-to-different-robots-txt-via-htaccess

I just want to be sure that it wouldn't damage SEO side of the system.

Comment: Please explain more, why you want to redirect ?

Comment: If you redirect the robots and crawlers will be redirected to another page also

Comment: Call particular domain related robots.txt using htaccess. You can create domain wise robots.txt

Comment: I have added extra information about this issue. Jack, are you referring to having rewriterule that would replace robots.txt with robotsCom.txt?

Answer (score 0):

You damage your SEO when search engines are not capable of accessing your `robots.txt` at all.

Not using standard practices regarding the location of your `robots.txt` is equivalent to taking a risk. Some search engines may handle your case well, others may frown and find it suspicious.

In one of the links you mention, a [solution](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/64777/10346) is suggested to avoid rewriting the URL. I would stick to it.